# Связь Navicat с виртуальной машиной Centos

Tags: виртуальная-машина, centos8

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, на Windows 10 создал виртуальную машину через Vmware workstation поставил Centos 8, в ней установил Mysql.
Через windows 10 winscp у меня получается к ней подключиться, а Navicat не может с ней связаться.

Я в этом деле абсолютный новичок, знаний нет и не знаю в какую сторону копать.